# On reboot headphones are muted

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

After I upgraded Ubuntu to 15.04 alsamixer mutes my headphones on every reboot. I have tried changing settings in alasamixer and saving it with `sudo alsactl store.`
I've edited file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` by commenting line `#load-module module-switch-on-port-available`
I've edited file `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf` like this:

```
[Element Speaker]
; link to muting
switch = mute
; set volume to zero, so only the master slider controls playback volume. This gives better linearity.
volume = zero
```

But nothing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new version of Ubuntu and new motherboard it fixed it by itself.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone poor like me, searching all over around and only got it fixed after ... one year.
Short Answer:
Try this command:

```
 pactl set-sink-port <card> <port>
```

Example: I have two sound card, Card #0 and Card #1

```
pactl set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones
```

You can get your card number and port by this command

```
pactl list
```

If that make your sound output correctly, you can persist that to default (i.e. every system boot or login) by putting this line into `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
set-sink-port 1 analog-output-headphones
```

Long answer:
My system has both PulseAudio and Alsamixer installed (default in Ubuntu 16.04). I install both `pavucontrol' and`gnome-alsamixer` to monitor things happen.

When I plugged my headphone jack in, PulseAudio can not detect the plugged-in state. It is still showed 'Unplugged'. In PulseAudio Volumn Control, I change ananlog output port to Headphone, then watch in AlsaMixer, I see that the Headphone is automatically unmuted, and volumn set to 100% level.

That means all methods on tweaking AlsaMixer will never work. We need to fix the PulseAudio, to set to the output port we want, by those commands I wrote above.

Comment: thanks! I had to use pavucontrol before, after every boot, to switch output, which became annoying really fast...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Dell 27 All in One.

The only workaround for me was to add a command to `/etc/rc.local`

The steps are:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following command before the `exit 0` line

```
sleep 10 && amixer -q set Headphone 100 unmute
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't solve my problem.